# typescript - How can i get object class instance?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, typescript

I have an object of class **classA** which was inherited from class **classB**

My question is: how do i know if my object was inherited from **classB**

I tried:
**Object instanceof classB**

But it’s not working!

when i am ading instanceof to any ts file
im getting

0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'prototype': object is null or undefined

```
var __extends = this.__extends || function (d, b) {
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    __.prototype = b.prototype; //exception occurs in this line
    d.prototype = new __();
};
```

Comment: You should try posting the code you're actually using.

Comment: This is hardly too localized. The question could be phrased better with better example code, but that doesn't make the actual question too specific.

Answer (score 5):

One cause of this error is if the class you are deriving from comes *after* the derived class in your file.

This (to mangle Ryan's answer):

```
class B extends A {
}

class A {
}

var x = new B();
console.log(x instanceof A); // Error
```

... causes precisely the error you describe in the [Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=%0A%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20A%20%7B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20A%20%7B%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20x%20=%20new%20B%28%29;%0Aconsole.log%28x%20instanceof%20A%29;%20//%20true).

I think there is already a work item for this on codeplex, but it's late, and I haven't checked...

Answer (score 2):

This generally does work:

```
class A {
}

class B extends A {
}

var x = new B();
console.log(x instanceof A); // true
```

Comment: when ever i add "instanceof" to ts file i am getting

0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'prototype': object is null or undefined